# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row?

Tags: magento2, error

When i have upload image from backend  and save it but this image not saved bellow error display.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bisquehaus_db6`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_A6C6C8FAA386736921D3A7C4B50B1185` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_media_gall), query
>   was: INSERT INTO`
>   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
>   `(`value_id`,`entity_id`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
>   value_id`= VALUES(`value_id`),`entity_id`= VALUES(`entity_id`)

screenshot

[image]

How to solve it? Please help me?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: When I have repair our database then my issue was resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired the Magento 2 database via CLI and my issue was resolved
using below URL
https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-repair-magento-2-database.html